# product of $k$ numbers

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic

The following problem arises in my combinatorics problem. Kindly share your thought. Thank you.

Let $k$ be a positive integer. Does there exists distinct **positive integers** $a_1,\dots,a_k$ such that for $1 \le j \le k$,

$\prod_{i=1}^j a_i \equiv 0 \text{ mod }(k)$ if and only if $j=k$?

Comment: Let $a_1=a_2=\ldots a_{k-1}=1, a_k=k$  What is the $m$ in the title?

Comment: Ok, I have fixed the comment to make $a_k$ positive

Comment: @RossMillikan very sorry. I need $a_i$s to be distinct.

Comment: For $k$ prime, you can take $a_i=i$, for example.  You can also take$ a_i=ik+1$ except $a_k=k$ for any $k$.  There are many solutions.  You have one equation in many unknowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  Let $p$ be a prime not dividing $k$ and let $a_i=p^i$ for $i=1,\dots, k-1$ and $a_k=k$.

Clearly $\prod\limits_{i=1}^j a_i$ is not a multiple of $k$ for $j<k$ because it is a power of $p$ and $p$ is coprime to $k$.